# List returns count > 0 but prints empty list in Unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a List of `spawnedPieces` that tracks the spawned pieces. After initiating the pieces I add the them to the list through `spawnedPieces.Add(piece)`.
When I print `spawnedPieces.Count` it returns correctly, but when I want to print the List it prints nothing.

I occurred to this problem when wanting to destroy/delete the game objects in the `spawnedPieces` List, but realized nothing gets destroyed, since the list does not show anything despite it counting elements.

```
void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log("start checking ground: " + groundPlacement.GroundSet());
        if (groundPlacement.GroundSet())
        {
            if (maxSpawns > 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(InitiateSpawn());
                maxSpawns--;
            }

            foreach (GameObject piece in spawnedPieces)
            {
                Debug.Log("spawnedPieces:\n" + piece.name + piece.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
private IEnumerator InitiateSpawn()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(SpawningRandomObjects());
    }
```

```
private IEnumerator SpawningRandomObjects()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, waitSpawnTime));
        Vector3 randomPosition = RandomPosition();

        GameObject spawnedPiece = Instantiate(RandomGamePiece(gamePieces), randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        spawnedPieces.Add(spawnedPiece);

        Debug.Log("instantiated at: " + randomPosition.ToString() + "spawnedPieces.Count: " + spawnedPieces.Count);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, waitSpawnTime));
    }
```

[image: first instantiated game object/piece]

[image: 5th instantiation]

I want a list containing all spawned pieces.

Comment: could you post your complete class? are both logs from the same instance?

Comment: But it prints correctly... "JumpingMuffin(Clone)" and its position. What's wrong? There is one piece and it prints...

Comment: @crackanddie it is always only that peace despite one peace being added with a different random position I suppose

Comment: btw that `InitiateSpawn` is quite redundant ... ;) why not just directly `StartCoroutine(SpawningRandomObjects());` .. have in mind though that this will **NOT** delay the rest of the `Update` method -> you are printing the list **before** you add the new item in the Coroutine .. would probably rather move that list print to the bottom of the `SpawningRandomObjects` .. also that trailing `yield return new WaitForSeconds` does absolutely nothing since nothing else is executed after it is done

Comment: could you show us the whole class? Or if you don't want to post the code of your class it can be some smiple class, where the problem occures too.